# How do I remove a set of cached items in Rails without knowing the exact key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have the following issue:

I have an index controller for Products, and the index controller can have a endless combination of query strings, ie.

```
/products?category=5&color=6
```

Now, it's easy enough to store all of these by using the params as key:

```
caches_action :index, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }
```

The problem comes in when you need to clear all of the index caches when a product gets added, removed or changed. As far as I know, you need to know the key to expire the cached object. You can't do something like the following in the sweeper:

```
def after_update(product)
   expire_action(product, :all)
end
```

I've looked into cache tagging a bit, but cannot get the Gems I looked at the do what I need, or actually get them to work at all. Them gems I looked at are [Cashier](https://github.com/twinturbo/cashier) and [Rails-Cache-Tags](https://github.com/take-five/rails-cache-tags). I tried doing the following with Cashier:

```
caches_action :index, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }, :tag => "products"
```

and in the sweeper file use:

```
Cashier.expire "products"
```

but when trying anything with Cashier it gives the following error:

```
uninitialized class variable @@adapter in Cashier
```

Using rails-cache-tags I've tried doing the following:

```
caches_action :index, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }, :tags => %w(products)
```

and then using the following in the sweeper file:

```
cache.delete_tag "products"
```

But that didn't work - it didn't clear the cache. What is the correct way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`expire_fragment`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment) which can take a `Regexp` as an argument:

> Will remove any fragment that matches, so `%r{pages/\d*/notes}` might remove all notes.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work with Memcache. "Note: Regexp expiration is only supported on caches that can iterate over all keys (unlike memcached)." I guess a workaround for this would be to use Redis, but I'm ideally looking for a solution that's compatible with any form of caching.